# VB.net dynamic Label listing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, label

I want to create a dynamic `Label` list. People can insert a number and their name, click the change `Button` and if the number is without any other entry, the text in the `Label` should change to the name. Of course all old entries should remain.

So here is my attempt:

Default.aspx

```html
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtnumber" runat="server" Width="25px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Create" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn3" runat="server" Text="Change" />
        <br />
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.vb

```html
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub _Default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim x As Integer = Application("eCount")

        For i = 1 To x

            Dim xName As String = Application("eName")
            Dim myLabel As Label = New Label()

            If Application("eNummer") = i And Application("blocked" + i.ToString()) = False Then
                myLabel.ID = "MyLabel" + i.ToString()
                myLabel.Text = i.ToString() & " " & xName & "<br>"
                ph.Controls.Add(myLabel)

                Application("blocked" + i.ToString()) = True
                Application("blockname" + i.ToString()) = xName

            ElseIf Application("eNummer") = i And Application("blocked" + i.ToString()) = True Then
                myLabel.ID = "MyLabel" + i.ToString()
                myLabel.Text = i.ToString() & " " & Application("blockname" + i.ToString()) & "<br>"
                ph.Controls.Add(myLabel)
            Else
                myLabel.ID = "MyLabel" + i.ToString()
                myLabel.Text = i.ToString() & " Noch nicht vergeben!" & "<br>"
                ph.Controls.Add(myLabel)
            End If

        Next i
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click

        Application("eCount") = txtnumber.Text

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click

        Application("eNummer") = txtnumber.Text
        Application("eName") = txtname.Text

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It would help if you described how what happens when you use this code differs from what you want to happen.

Comment: Thx Blackwood! I will create a LIst, in this List you cann add your Name by insert the Number in the first field, and your name in the secon field. If you press change, your name will be added after the number you chose. The problem is, the List creation deletes all the other Names in the List and only show the Name that is adding right now. So after the first adding it should create a dynamic application variable Application("blocked" + i.ToString()) = True
Application("blockname" + i.ToString()) = xName so if the Page is loaded and the Next forward reached the

Comment: Application("blockname" + i.ToString()) it should insert the Name that is already added to the List. I Hope you know what i mean